# iwconfig not showing any wireless interfaces in kali linux vm

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

Version

```
uname -a
Linux kali 5.18.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.5-1kali6 (2022-07-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried installing backports following [this](https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=753.0) and ran into a bunch of errors during `make`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v5.15.58/backports-5.15.58-1.tar.xz
tar -xvf backports-5.15.58-1.tar.xz
cd backports-5.15.58-1
```

followed by

```
$ sudo make defconfig-wifi

cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
lex -ozconf.lex.c -L zconf.l
yacc -ozconf.tab.c -t -l zconf.y
zconf.y:34.1-7: warning: POSIX Yacc does not support %expect [-Wyacc]
   34 | %expect 32
      | ^~~~~~~
zconf.y:97.1-11: warning: POSIX Yacc does not support %destructor [-Wyacc]
   97 | %destructor {
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf

WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET_ENABLE
  Depends on [n]: USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && n && m && BP_MODULES [=y] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  Selected by [m]:
  - USB_BELKIN [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  - USB_ARMLINUX [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]

WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET_ENABLE
  Depends on [n]: USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && n && m && BP_MODULES [=y] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  Selected by [m]:
  - USB_BELKIN [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  - USB_ARMLINUX [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

here's what happens with `make` (truncated)

```
sudo make               
make[5]: 'conf' is up to date.

WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET_ENABLE
  Depends on [n]: USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && n && m && BP_MODULES [=y] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  Selected by [m]:
  - USB_BELKIN [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  - USB_ARMLINUX [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]

WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET_ENABLE
  Depends on [n]: USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && n && m && BP_MODULES [=y] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  Selected by [m]:
  - USB_BELKIN [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
  - USB_ARMLINUX [=y] && USB_NET_DRIVERS [=m] && USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET [=m]
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc-11 (Debian 11.3.0-3) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-11 (Debian 11.3.0-5) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/compat/main.o
  LD [M]  /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/compat/compat.o
  CC [M]  /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/admtek/adm8211.o
In file included from /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/include/net/mac80211.h:21,
                 from /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/admtek/adm8211.c:24:
/home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/include/net/cfg80211.h: In function ‘wdev_address’:
/home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/include/net/cfg80211.h:5504:36: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
 5504 |                 return wdev->netdev->dev_addr;
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common/include/linux/string.h:253,
                 from /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/backport-include/linux/string.h:3,                    \
      |                           ^
/home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/cfg80211.c:3806:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘memcpy’
 3806 |         memcpy(ndev->dev_addr, ar->mac_addr, ETH_ALEN);
      |         ^~~~~~
/home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/cfg80211.c:3808:35: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*ndev->dev_addr’
 3808 |                 ndev->dev_addr[0] = (ndev->dev_addr[0] ^ (1 << fw_vif_idx)) |
      |                                   ^
/home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/cfg80211.c:3812:43: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(ndev->dev_addr + 4)’
 3812 |                         ndev->dev_addr[4] ^= 0x80;
      |                                           ^~
make[8]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:293: /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/cfg80211.o] Error 1
make[7]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:555: /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl] Error 2
make[6]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:555: /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath] Error 2
make[5]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:555: /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1/drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.18.0-kali5-common/Makefile:1858: /home/cycl0n3/Desktop/backports-5.15.58-1] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile.build:13: modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile.real:88: modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:43: modules] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:30: default] Error 2
```

I tried `make -i` to ignore this error and a few more instead followed by installation and reboot. Then no wireless interfaces are detected still.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is that your Kali Linux VM sees an Ethernet connection. My Kali (and Ubuntu) VMs also see an Ethernet connection.

This is entirely normal in a standard Virtual machine setup.  A guest VM uses the network "hardware" supplied by the Virtual Machine App.  I have VMware on one computer and Hyper-V on the other computer.

Guest machines get Video, Audio, Disk, Network connection, Mouse and so on from the Virtual Machine App.

If you want the Kali machine to have its own wireless, your need to obtain a USB Wireless Card and then use USB Passthrough in the Virtual Machine App to assign the USB card to Kali. Make sure the card has Linux drivers.

This is for VMware and VBOX. Hyper-V does not readily support passthrough

Comment: it's vmware fusion and is it possible to grant the vm access to the host's hardware? I was under the impression that `backports` should solve the problem without running kali directly as a dual boot or having to use an external wireless card which I don't have.

Comment: For VMware you need to supply a Wireless USB and use Passthrough. You do not need dual boot to do this.

Comment: but can't use the host's wireless card instead?

Comment: Not is WMware (I have used this for a very long time)

Comment: Again, this is something very BASIC, that anyone using Kali SHOULD know. Actually this and a lot more.